# Strange NSData Output

Tags: objective-c, ios, post, utf-8, nsdata

I have some unexpected results coming from the following code:

```
- (NSData *)postDataWithDict:(NSDictionary *)postDict
{
    // Assume key is urlValid
    NSUInteger postCount = [postDict count];
    NSMutableArray *buildArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:postCount];
    for (NSString *key in postDict) {
        //post data is key=value&key=value&key=value...

        // start with key
        NSMutableString *arrayLine = [NSMutableString stringWithString:key];

        [arrayLine appendString:@"="];

        // analyze and then append value
        id postValue = [postDict objectForKey:key];
        if ([postValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",postValue];
            [arrayLine appendString:valueString];
        }
        else if ([postValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            NSString *urlEncodedString = [self urlEncodeValue:postValue];
            [arrayLine appendString:urlEncodedString];
        }
        else {

            NSLog(@"postKey: %@, postValue class:%@", key, [postValue class]);
            NSError *jsonError = nil;
            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postValue
                                                               options:0
                                                                 error:&jsonError];
            if (jsonError != nil) {
                NSLog(@"JSON serialization failed: %@ - %@", [jsonError localizedDescription], [jsonError userInfo]);
                NSLog(@"value: %@", postValue);
            }
            else {
                // need to urlencode
                NSString *stringifyJSON = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[jsonData bytes]];
                NSString *urlJSONstring = [self urlEncodeValue:stringifyJSON];
                [arrayLine appendString:urlJSONstring];
            }
        }
        [buildArray addObject:arrayLine];
    }
    NSString *postString = [buildArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
    NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //testing
    NSLog(@"Post Dict: %@", postDict);
    NSLog(@"Post Array: %@", buildArray);
    NSLog(@"Post String: %@", postString);
    NSLog(@"Post Data: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[postData bytes]]);

    return postData;
}
```

My //testing log results:

```
 Post Dict: {
    authenticationString = b3210c0bc6d2c47f4c2f7eeea12e063d;
    dataMode = updateSingle;
    dateCreated = "374300293.81108";
    dateModified = "374609294.313093";
    dateSynced = "374610683.588062";
    entityName = CommodityTypes;
    myName = 21;
    sortKey = 21;
    username = iPhoneAdamek;
    usernameString = iPhoneAdamek;
    uuidKey = "53403EAE-DD4F-4226-A979-316EF7F43991";
}
```

Post Dict looks good. Just what I wanted.

```
2012-11-14 13:31:23.640 FoodyU[11393:907] Post Array: (
    "myName=21",
    "dataMode=updateSingle",
    "dateSynced=374610683.588062",
    "uuidKey=53403EAE-DD4F-4226-A979-316EF7F43991",
    "sortKey=21",
    "dateModified=374609294.313093",
    "entityName=CommodityTypes",
    "dateCreated=374300293.81108",
    "authenticationString=b3210c0bc6d2c47f4c2f7eeea12e063d",
    "usernameString=iPhoneAdamek",
    "username=iPhoneAdamek"
)
```

Post Array looks good. Strings are all set to be concatenated for a HTTP POST string.

```
2012-11-14 13:31:23.641 FoodyU[11393:907] Post String: myName=21&dataMode=updateSingle&dateSynced=374610683.588062&uuidKey=53403EAE-DD4F-4226-A979-316EF7F43991&sortKey=21&dateModified=374609294.313093&entityName=CommodityTypes&dateCreated=374300293.81108&authenticationString=b3210c0bc6d2c47f4c2f7eeea12e063d&usernameString=iPhoneAdamek&username=iPhoneAdamek
```

Post String looks good. I'm ready to convert it to data to use in `[NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPBody:postData]`.

```
2012-11-14 13:31:23.643 FoodyU[11393:907] Post Data: myName=21&dataMode=updateSingle&dateSynced=374610683.588062&uuidKey=53403EAE-DD4F-4226-A979-316EF7F43991&sortKey=21&dateModified=374609294.313093&entityName=CommodityTypes&dateCreated=374300293.81108&authenticationString=b3210c0bc6d2c47f4c2f7eeea12e063d&usernameString=iPhoneAdamek&username=iPhoneAdamekoneAdamek;
    usernameString = iPhoneAdamek;
    uuidKey = "53403EAE-DD4F-4226-A
```

WTF??? How did `&username=iPhoneAdamek` become `&username=iPhoneAdamekoneAdamek;
        usernameString = iPhoneAdamek;
        uuidKey = "53403EAE-DD4F-4226-A`?

I'm fairly new to Cocoa. Is there something wrong with:

```
NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or

```
NSLog(@"Post Data: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[postData bytes]]);
```

Comment: nothing wrong with those too lines, clear the code and leave only the relevant parts so that people can help you.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using `NSLog` of `NSData` as,

```
NSLog(@"Post Data: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[postData bytes]]);
```

Instead use it as,

```
NSLog(@"Post Data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

`[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[postData bytes]]` always returns unexpected results.

As per [documentation for bytes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/bytes),

**`bytes:`** *Returns a pointer to the receiver’s contents.*

And as per [Apple documentation for `stringWithUTF8String`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithUTF8String%3a),

**`stringWithUTF8String:`**
*Returns a string created by copying the data from a given C array of UTF8-encoded bytes.*
Parameters: `bytes` - **A NULL-terminated C array of bytes in UTF8 encoding.**

So when you are using `[postData bytes]`, it is not **NULL-terminated** and hence when you are using with `stringWithUTF8String` returns the data written in memory till it encounters a NULL-termination.